# Tangents and differentiability

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Was just going through my single variable calculus notes recently when I came across this interesting article on the relation between differentiabilty of a function. I missed some of the points my professor made and hence a few doubts remain in my mind -

1. Can a function be differentiable at a point and still have no tangent at that point?
2. Can a function have a tangent at a point and still be non-differentiable at the point?

Comment: Don't mix functions with their graph. The tangent line to the *graph of a funtion* has slope which is the derivative of the function.

Comment: We all know what a derivative is. But what is a tangent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiability at a point, for a real-valued function of one variable, is the same as the existence of a tangent line at that point, except for one case: If the tangent line is vertical, then the function is not differentiable at that point. It's because a vertical line isn't represented by any linear function, and differentiability is really about looking locally like a linear function.

Thus, the answer to your first question is "no", and the answer to your second question is "yes, consider $y=x^{1/3}$ at $(0,0)$"

Comment: Thanks! The second point you made about $y=x^{1/3}$ - so is it correct to conclude that if a function has a *unique* tangent at point, it'll be differentiable at that point?

Comment: No, the cube root function has a unique tangent line at the origin, namely the y-axis. What's required is a non-vertical tangent line.

Comment: So is it a necessary condition that the tangent be unique for the function to be differentiable? For instance, for $y=|x|$, the tangent at origin - does it exist? If yes, then is it unique?

Comment: @Mathguy the tangent being unique is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is the tangent must be unique **and** be non-vertical

Comment: So unique, non vertical tangent implies differentiability? On the other hand, differentiability at a point always implies existence of a tangent? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, basically. The only funny part is the idea about uniqueness of a tangent line. If it exists, it's unique; there's no question of there being more than one. The graph of $y=|x|$ has no tangent line at $(0,0)$, not two of them.

Comment: Hw exactly do you define a tangent then? Like I could draw many lines touching $y=|x|$ at $x=0.$ Which one is te tangent?

Comment: None of them are tangent, because a tangent line is one that the curve "matches" if you zoom in at that point. More precisely, the distance between the tangent line and the curve has to approach zero faster than any linear function as we approach the point of tangency from either side. That's the definition of tangent line that you want to use when talking about differentiability.

Comment: This is the intuition you want for differentiability of a single-variable function: The function is differentiable at a point if zooming in sufficiently makes it look more and more like the graph of a linear function defined at that point. Zooming into the cusp of the absolute value graph more and more leaves it still looking like a cusp, not like a single straight line.

Comment: So how would you find the tangent for a non differentiable function? Will it still be called a tangent even if the function is non-differentiable? Many thanks for your help sir, btw!

Comment: The only time there would be a tangent at a non-differentiable point would be if the tangent line were vertical. You can tell there's a vertical tangent line because the derivative approaches infinity at that point.

Comment: Also, if you define a function parametrically, vertical tangent lines are not a problem. Taking $x(t)=t^3$ and $y(t)=t$, you get the graph $y=x^{1/3}$, and its tangent line points in the direction of the vector $\left<x'(t),y'(t)\right>$, which at $(0,0)$ is the vector $\left<0,1\right>$

Comment: If there are more than one 'lines that touch the curve' at a point, can we conclude that the function is non differentiable at that point?

Comment: That seems right, yes. Ultimately, it's not the "touching" property that makes a line tangent; it's the difference between the line and the curve being smaller than any linear function. Note that the vertical tangent to the cube root graph we've been discussing actually cuts through the curve at that point.

Comment: Just to clarify this, consider $y=x^{(2/3)}$ at origin. The function is non differentiable and hence has no tangent at origin. However, the lines that seem to touch the curve at origin are not considered tangents - why?

Comment: Take a line like y=0, which touches the graph at $(0,0)$. The graph does not locally look like that line near the origin. More precisely, the difference between $y=x^(2/3)$ and $y=0$ is a function that remains larger than non-zero linear functions near $0$. For contrast, look at the difference between $y=x^2+x$ and $y=x$ near the origin. You get a parabola which becomes smaller than every non-zero linear function as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: More succinctly, it's not a tangent line if you can fit other straight lines between it and your curve.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13563/discussion-between-mathguy-and-g-tony-jacobs)

Comment: Actually, I have to run now. Take care, though! :)

Answer (score 1):

If a function is differentiable at some point $(x_0,y_0)$ with slope $m$, then the tangent is $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$. And so, the first proposition is false.

As for the second proposition, it is true, yes a function can have a tangent without being differentiable. Consider the function $$y=\sqrt{25-x^2}$$

It has tangents $x=5$ and $x=-5$ but it is not differntiable at these points of tangency.